# Elixir invalid string

Tags: elixir

I tried the following code in iex:

```
iex(13)> String.valid?(<<128>>)
false
iex(14)> String.valid?(<<191>>)
false
```

Why aren't both valid strings?

Comment: Did you try `String.valid?(<<128::utf8>>)` instead? `<<128::utf8>>` gives you the binary composed of the single utf8 codepoint "128": `<<194, 128>>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Ramon Snir said, you need to use `utf8`. From the Getting Started Guide:

> A string is a UTF-8 encoded binary. In order to understand exactly what we mean by that, we need to understand the difference between bytes and code points.
>
> ...
>
> When representing code points in bytes, we need to encode them somehow. Elixir chose the UTF-8 encoding as its main and default encoding. When we say a string is a UTF-8 encoded binary, we mean a string is a bunch of bytes organized in a way to represent certain code points, as specified by the UTF-8 encoding.

```
<<128 :: utf8>> |> String.valid? # => true
```

You can read more at: [Binaries, strings and char lists](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/binaries-strings-and-char-lists.html)

Comment: The guide says "UTF-8 as its main and default encoding". IO.puts(<<65>>) returns A :ok but IO.puts(<<128>>) returns an error... why?